# NodeJS MSSQL Module Executing only Part of Stored Proc

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

So I have a node server, and I have it kicking off a stored proc for one particular internal tool.  However, it seems it is dying part way through (seems to be once dynamic sql is used).

So it does a bunch of general sql commands, but seems to be dying when we hit:

```
set @cmd = N'Some stuff'
print @cmd
exec(@cmd)
```

my js server code is:

```
            var connection2 = new sql.Connection(config2, function(err){

            console.log("Connection 2 error - "+ err);

            var request2 = connection2.request();

            var spName = "nameOfSP";

            console.log("---calling sp----");

            request2.execute(spName,function(response){
                    console.log("SP response " + response);

                })
            });
```

I am getting this error:

```
SP response RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms
```

However, I am getting confirmation that the steps up until that dynamic sql is getting process almost instantaneously.

I've tried adding:

connectionTimeout: 30000

to my config, but it didn't seem to effect anything, which is making me feel like I'm not implementing that correctly.  The documentation for this doesn't show much for this part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: looks like the sql you are generating is running very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I was specifying connectionTimeout, rather than requestTimeout.

This fixed it.